# Setting state when react router renders a new component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Ok, have an accordion component, which would have all its tabs closed by default (only one tab is dynamic in the below code) and to automatically be opened if the users has enter the component from a specific link:

```
class Me extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        const routerState = this.props.location.state;
        this.state = { showCourses: routerState ? routerState.showCourses : false };
        this.coursesHandler = this.coursesHandler.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    coursesHandler () {
        var toggle = !this.state.showCourses;
        this.setState({ showCourses: toggle })
    }

    logout () {
        window.localStorage.removeItem('celledCredentials');
        this.props.logout();
        hashHistory.push('/');
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="me-page-title">CHECK YOUR PROGRESS!</h1>
                <h2 className="me-page-subtitle" onClick={this.coursesHandler}>Courses</h2>
                {this.state.showCourses && <CoursesList /> }
                <h2 className="me-page-subtitle not-active">Personal Information</h2>
                <h2 className="me-page-subtitle not-active">Log in information</h2>
                <h2 onClick={this.logout} className="me-page-subtitle not-active">Logout</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ logout }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Me);
```

The thing is, I need to add a link to the open tabbed version of the component (say, state.showCourses === true).

I managed to get it to work using the "state" parameter inside the Link component of react-router. See the code render method from the main component below:

```
render () {

        return (
            <div className="cm-page-container">
                <Link to={{ pathname: '/me', state: { showCourses: true } }}><h1 className="cm-page-title">{this.props.mainCourse.moduleData['main-title']}</h1></Link>
                <h2 className="cm-page-subtitle">{this.props.mainCourse.moduleData['sub-title']}</h2>
                <AudioPlayer audioUrl={this.props.mainCourse.audioUrl} />
                <h3 className="cm-page-chat-title">MESSAGES</h3>
                <Chat messages={this.props.mainCourse.messages} />
                <UserInput disable={this.props.mainCourse.inputDisable} submitUserAnswer={this.submitUserAnswer} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is working, but I guess is not really elegant and I am sure there is a better way of doing it. Am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either push this state to the redux-store that it seems that you are using since you have connect, and dispatch actions to open/close it, making the component stateless and thus pushing all state into redux. Or you can also update state in componentWillReceiveProps if the querystring you expect the router route to have is present. Then you want need to handle local state in your route.

Comment: Will update the state in componentWillReceiveProps wouldn't be the same I am doing now? Also, is there any advantage in using a query key instead of a state one? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would, but you would only have on place to manage that components logic. The only advantage of querystring would be deeplinking in your case id guess

Comment: Ok I end up managing all in the redux state, thanks for your help!

Comment: That sounds reasonable, its also cleaner and more traceable having it in the redux-state.